# Java Network Discovery

Tags: java, networking, discovery

I'm running a Java application on my PC which involves migration of virtual machines running on my physical machine.
How can I connect to other physical machines on my network so that I can
1. Get info eg virtual machines running on them, emulator used etc. without the application being run on the client machine.
2. The network discovery must be automatic i.e. as soon as any PC is connected to the network, my machine should come up with all possible details of the PC.
3. I don't intend pinging all the computers on the network. I don't want any application run on the client machine. My machine should do the network discovery and info gathering by itself.

Could someone pls help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You have alot of questions in there and no information whatsoever. If you could give us a hint about your virtualization infrastructure than we would atleast have a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do the first part. This is how its done- 1. Open a connection to the qemu hypervisor on the destination physical machine through ssh. 2. use the same connect variable and Libvirt's functions to get the details about the other virtual machines running on the physical machine.

Answer (score 1):

For 2 you should consider using Zeroconf as Apple do.  For Java choose http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've figured out a way to do the first part. This is how its done- 1. Open a connection to the qemu hypervisor on the destination physical machine through ssh. 2. use the same connect variable and Libvirt's functions to get the details about the other virtual machines running on the physical machine.